# Rails association not making intended SQL query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been trying to understand how to make a friends association using rails like in Facebook. I first created a way of making friend request and then to add a friend I added another model called friendship.

User.rb :

```
  class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_one :homepage
  has_many :friend_requests, foreign_key: "sender_id"
  has_many :pending_requests, foreign_key: "receiver_id", class_name: "FriendRequest"

  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, through: :friendships, source: "friend_a"
end
```

friendship.rb :

```
class Friendship < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :friend_a, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "friend_a_id"
    belongs_to :friend_b, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "friend_b_id"
    
end
```

Everything seems to be working except when I call User.friends . The SQL query that it makes does not make use of the foreign key friend_a_id but uses user_id in the friendship table which does not exist. How do I make sure that rails makes the correct SQL query.

Command Line Output :

```
irb(main):001:0> User.first.friends
   (2.8ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "friendships" ON "users"."id" = "friendships"."friend_a_id" WHERE "friendships"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 3]]
(Object doesn't support #inspect)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would preferer create two has_many for each friendship relationship and after create union methods with ActiveRecordExtended (If you are using psql) or ActiveRecordUnion gems:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :friendships_a, class_name: "FriendShip", foreign_key: "friend_a_id", dependent: :destroy_all, inverse_of: :friend_a
  has_many :friends_a, through: :friendships_a

  has_many :friendships_b, class_name: "FriendShip", foreign_key: "friend_b_id", dependent: :destroy_all, inverse_of: :friend_b
  has_many :friends_b, through: :friendships_b

  # For this method you need https://github.com/brianhempel/active_record_union or https://github.com/georgekaraszi/ActiveRecordExtended
  def friends
    friends_b.union(friends_a)
  end
end
```

```
class Friendship < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :friend_a, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "friend_a_id"
    belongs_to :friend_b, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "friend_b_id" 
end
```